# ArrayList как узнать индекс элемента если известно значение?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, index

Можно ли в [java](/questions/tagged/java) узнать индекс элемента в `ArrayList`, если известно значение?

При нажатии на пункт списка показывает значения

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mFilteredCheeses.size();
}

public void filter(String query) {
    mFilteredCheeses = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String cheese : mDefaultCheeses) {
        if(cheese.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
            mFilteredCheeses.add(cheese);
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

А есть ли возможность узнать индекс элемента, например со значением `Макс`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Есть у ArrayList метод [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) - он как раз  ищет подходящий элемент и выводит его индекс.

```
ArrayList<Object> test = new ArrayList<>();
test.add("yo");
test.add("yo2");
System.out.println(test.indexOf("yo2")); // Выведет: 1
```

Если в списке несколько одинаковых значений, то выведет индекс первого попавшегося.

Comment: Стоит добавить, что может понадобиться переопределение методов `equals()` и `hashCode()` объектов

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вы правы, но на половину. [hashCode()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/AbstractList.java#AbstractList.indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) не используется

Comment: Спасибо! все правильно. Но все равно, то что хотел сделать так и не получилось(

Answer (score 2):

Смотря что Вы хотите сделать под формулировкой **макс**.
Если это последний индекс нужного элемента то   `lastIndexOf(value)`.
Можно через цикл, и там через условие то что Вам надо. напишите подробнее если это не подходит.

```
    ArrayList<Object> test = new ArrayList<>();
    test.add("yo");
    test.add("yo2");
    test.add("yo3");
    test.add("yo2");
    System.out.println(test.indexOf("yo2"));
    System.out.println(test.lastIndexOf("yo2"));
```

Comment: Спасибо! Уже разобрался