# Как узнать номер элемента в столбце?

Tags: java

Например: `Anuj` 5-ый по списку.

```
public class Run {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();

        obj.add("Ajeet");
        obj.add("Harry");
        obj.add("Chaitanya");
        obj.add("Steve");
        obj.add("Anuj");
    }    
}
```

Comment: `obj.indexOf("Anuj")`

Comment: @AlexChermenin это еще не ответ, но уже не комментарий

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [ArrayList как узнать индекс элемента если известно значение?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/567168/arraylist-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: @defaultlocale язык другой же :)

Comment: @AlexChermenin нашел на Java, спасибо за замечание.

Comment: Alex Chermenin спасибо